# Autowiring bean with Hashmap populated from application properties not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I want to pass values of a Hashmap to the CLI from the Spring Boot Application. I am getting a Null pointer exception. Please let me know what is wrong here?

Application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz.movie*"})
public class Application  implements CommandLineRunner{
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
MovieCollections movieCollections;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    try {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
    //  MovieCollections collections = (MovieCollections) context.getBean("movieCollections");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(movieCollections==null) {
            System.out.println("it is null");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("it is NOT null");
            System.out.println(movieCollections.getMovieCollectionMap());
        }

        System.out.println("Select Movie: ");
        **// NULL POINTER  HERE**
        for(String s:movieCollections.getMovieCollectionMap().values()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

MovieCollections Class

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value ="application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="movies")

public class MovieCollections {

    private Map<String, String> movieCollectionMap;

    public Map<String, String> getMovieCollectionMap() {
        return movieCollectionMap;
    }

    public void setMovieCollectionMap(Map<String, String> movieCollectionMap) {
        this.movieCollectionMap = movieCollectionMap;
    }
```

MovieCollectionsBean.java

```
@Configuration
public class MovieCollectionBean {

    @Bean
    public MovieCollections getMovieCollections() {
        return new MovieCollections();
    }

}
```

applications.properties

```
movies.M1001=SpiderMan
movies.M1002=Thor
movies.M1003=Logan
movies.M1004=Conjuring2
movies.M1005=StarWars
```

I am getting a null map. Why the map is not getting populated.

Comment: Your `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MovieCollection.class)` needs to go on an `@Configuration` class. Don't declare a separate `@Bean` for it. Don't declare that `@PropertySource`--it's registered automatically by Boot.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your properties to `movies.names.M100...` and rename the field `movieCollectionMap` to `names` in `MovieCollections` class

When you use `@ConfigurationProperties`, the field names should match the property. So in this case, `prefix` is `movies`, the field name is `names` and the hashmap is keys with codes and values as the movie names

Also, you need to update the `getter` and `setter` methods appropriately.

Comment: Now i get the values. But Still there is this error stack trace:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
 at ort 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:364) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

Comment: I am assuming you updated your getters and setters as well? I can't answer until I see your updated code.

Comment: I added the property name in the properties - movies.movieCollectionMap.M1001=SpiderMan  The movieCollectionMap  already has getters and setters. as in the MovieCollections class.  What am i missing?

Comment: Since the question is related to configuration properties, and since that problem is solved, can you mark the answer and ask another question?

Comment: Sunil Your answer  helped. But is it possible to help solve the Null pointer that I still see?

Comment: Maybe upload your code somewhere like GitHub and share the link. It can be different problem. Reason I asked you to mark the answer is, you cannot update the question based on a solution and continue it. People won’t encourage it.